# IE10 doesn't support white-space: pre-wrap?

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-10

I have a `pre` tag in a resizable `div`. And the width of `pre` will stretch or contract when user expands or shrinks the `div`. If the text is longer than the `pre` width, it will be broken into next line.

I use this CSS for the pre:

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

This wokrs on FF, Chrome, IE8 and IE9, but not on IE10.

On IE10, when user expands it, the text will go the previous line if the width is adequate. It works OK. But things go bad when user shrinks it. The text will be hidden instead of being broken to the next line.

I change the `white-space: pre-wrap` to `white-space: pre` for IE10, it will break the text. However, the English words will be broken, too. I want to keep each single word no-wrap.

Comment: you may use the modernizr.js to verify it!

Comment: Not reproducible. Please provide a complete example, with text context sample.

Comment: This probably won't help, but in cases like this it's recommended to put the unprefixed version last, below the vendor-prefixed ones.

Answer (score 1):

IE10 does support `white-space: pre-wrap`. But IE10 is strict with the width of that element.

I use a resizable widget for the wapper container, but forget to resize the width of `<pre>`. It will be fixed if I resize/claim the width the `<pre>` when use expands or shrinks the wrapper `<div>`.

Comment: Could you clarify your answer?  I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @iconoclast I put `<pre>` inside a resizable `<div>`. The issue is caused by that I resize the outer `<div>` node but forget to update the element width of `<pre>`.